Show equivalence of two very long integrals.
I'm trying to show that the following integral $$\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^s f(x \vee s-b) \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}(2s-b)e^{-\frac{(2s-b)^2}{2t}-\mu(b+\frac{\mu t}{2})}db ds$$ is equal to $$\int_0^\infty f(y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\bigg[e^{2\mu y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x+y+\mu t)^2}{2t}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-y+\mu t)^2}{2t}}-2\mu e^{2\mu y}\int_{\frac{x+y+\mu t}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz\bigg]dy$$ as I have seen it stated without proof in a paper which simply said "a lengthy calculation shows" that they are equivalent. I have that $f$ is a $C^1$ function with bounded $f$ and $f'$ and also that $f(\infty)=0$. I began by splitting the first integral up into the sum of two integrals, the first running $s$ from $0$ to $x$ and the second from $x$ to $\infty$ thus removing the maximum from the integrand. I then attempted to integrate the inner integral by parts using a three variable integration by parts of the form $$\int u'vw = uvw - \int uv'w - \int uvw'$$ but this didn't appear to be particularly fruitful. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem and if integration by parts is what I should be attempting would be much appreciated.

Why not link the paper in case people want to investigate with context?
